# SQL foreign key of foreign key

Tags: sql, db2

First of all I´m working with DB2.

My problem:

- I have a table `A` with a primary key.
- A table `B` with 2 primary keys (one of them is a foreign key of `A`)
- A table `C` with a primary key
- A table `D` which has got the primary keys of `B` and `C`

How can I create table `D`?

My first idea was that, but it doesn't work:

```
Create Table D(
   A varchar(20) not null references B(A),
   B varchar(20) not null references B(name of prim key attribute from B),
   C varchar(20) not null references C,
   primary key(A,B,C)    
);
```

Hope you understand my problem and can help me.

Comment: A table can only ever have **ONE** primary key - what you probably mean is **a primary key** made up from **2 columns**

Comment: Or do you mean that table B has two separate columns, each unique by itself? Perhaps there is no need or significance to combining them as a composite key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foreign keys reference the names of columns, not the names of constraints.

The set up . . .

```
create table A (
  col_a int primary key
);

create table B (
  col_a int not null,
  col_b int not null,
  primary key (col_a, col_b),
  foreign key (col_a) references A (col_a)
);

create table C (
  col_c int primary key
);
```

And the execution . . .

```
create table D (
  col_a int not null,
  col_b int not null,
  col_c int not null,
  primary key (col_a, col_b, col_c),
  foreign key (col_a, col_b) references B (col_a, col_b),
  foreign key (col_c) references C (col_c)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Marc_s commented there can only be ONE primary key in a table ie, you cannot have more than one primary key in a table.

As a solution to your problem you can probably combine two columns of table  B and table C which can together act as a primary key for table D